# Definite integral with colored boundaries

Tags: color, integral

So I wanted to write down a definite integral from say a to b but I want a to be red and b to be green. I tried using:

```
\int_{a}^{b}
```

and it works great, but when I add color using `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` like

```
\int_{color{red}a}^{color{green}b}
```

`b` breaks out of the integral and becomes an exponent

also when I only add color to `b` like

```
\int_{a}^{\color{green}b}
```

`a` becomes green too instead of just b

does anyone know how to fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 \int_{\color{red}a}^{\color{green}b}f(x)dx
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: use `{{\color...}}` the superscript brace does not scope the color (or use `\mathcolor{red}{a}`)

Answer (score 5):

Just to follow up on @DavidCarlisle's comment: You need to write `{\color{...}...}`, not `color{...}...` for the terms in the lower and upper limits of integration.

Actually, if your TeX distribution is reasonably up to date -- say, mid-2022 or more recent -- you may want to use `\mathcolor{...}{...}` for math-y material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} % 'dvipsnames' option to access "JungleGreen" 

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathcolor{red}{a}}^{\mathcolor{JungleGreen}{b}} f(x)\,dx
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that \mathcolor or \textcolor even existed, also I specified the package because I am actually using "JungleGreen" instead and didn't want to eliminate the unlikely scenario of the package causing the problem.

Comment: @GeorgeGkoumas - Thanks. I'll go ahead and update my answer to employ "JungleGreen" instead of "blue". :-)

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule, avoid `\color` preferring `\textcolor` whenever possible, that is, almost always you just have a small chunk of text to colorize.

With recent LaTeX versions, you can use `\mathcolor` with the same syntax as `\textcolor` when in math, but when the object to be colored is a single ordinary atom, `\textcolor` works flawlessly (when you cannot update your LaTeX).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
 \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx
\\
 \int_{\mathcolor{red}{a}}^{\mathcolor{green}{b}}f(x)\,dx % <--- best
\\
 \int_{\textcolor{red}{a}}^{\textcolor{green}{b}}f(x)\,dx % <--- also works
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know \mathcolor and \textcolor existed